# Using runat="server" in stylesheet link not resolving

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm trying to include a stylesheet in one of my aspx pages. The stylesheet is in the directory `/Dir1/style.css` (relative to the project root). I'm trying to get it to resolve in a page that's at the path: `/Dir1/MyPage.aspx`. I'm aware that I could just include the stylesheet in the header, since it's in the same directory, but I'm trying to use the `runat="server"` tag so that it would be easier to move the page later if needed.

This is the line I'm using:

```
<link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Dir1/style.css" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Everything I read indicate this is supposed to work, but no matter what I do, I get a 404 in the browser for that stylesheet. The runat attribute doesn't seem to be doing anything - the path the browser is trying to fetch ends up being: `http://localhost:7205/Dir1/~/Dir1/style.css`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of .NET? I don't remember if they added that functionality in 4 or 4.5. Either way, I think you should be able to do `href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Dir1/style.css") %>"`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<link runat="server" rel="stylesheet" href="<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Dir1/style.css") %>" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

And you should not need the runat=server